# Programmable Wifi Relay / Power Switch?

Tags: switch-statement, embedded, wifi

I'm toying with the idea of a pet project..

I wanna make our coffee machine remote controlled by a web interface.

The idea is to hit a "make me coffee button" and have it poll the router get the MAC address list to see who's in the office and send them a growl notification (we all use macs) asking if they'd like coffee and then doing something with a relay to turn the coffee machine on..

Can you recommend a programmable wifi relay or small embedded system for this?

Comment: is your coffee maker part of the network? wifi coffee maker?

Comment: @Ibu Nope, thats what i need the relay for :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like everyones favourite microcontroller the [arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/) and a relay like [this](http://powerswitchtail.com) are a perfect match for nerdy coffee.

http://lifehacker.com/5726455/diy-twitter+powered-coffee-pot

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at those two things:

http://www.yoctopuce.com/EN/products/usb-actuators/yocto-powerrelay

http://www.yoctopuce.com/EN/products/extensions-and-networking/yoctohub-wireless

The YoctoHub-Wireless is a WiFi device able to control any other Yoctopuce device. 
This might cost you a little more than an Arduino based solution. But it's much easier to handle: the hardware part is already done, all you have to do is some programming.

If you want a more traditional approach, a WiFi enabled mini-computer and any USB relay would do the trick as well. Yoctopuce is not the only company to build USB relays, Phidgets for instance, have a whole lineup.